# bookmarklet javascript to get URL of all open tabs

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Is there any additional DOM exposed that a bookmarklet can access to get a list of the URLs of all the tabs that are currently open in a browser?  I have done some searching but have found very little documentation on what can be done in a bookmarklet which cannot be done in a normal web page - although having written some bookmarklets already it seems they have a bit more privileged status than a normal web page (although this seems to vary by browser).

Comment: I feel that bookmarklets only operate on the currently open tab's DOM and as such have no idea about other tabs in a browser so I don't think you can do this.  It would seem like a security risk to be able to access other page's DOMs from another tab.

Comment: no more of a security risk than allowing me to inject arbitrary javascript into any page i choose, which essentially is what a bookmarklet lets me do.

Comment: Right, but you're choosing to do it, per page.  You're basically just shoving another `<script>` tag into the page and loading up your own functions into the DOM.  I can't control another page that I didn't make from a page that I did.

Comment: I'm choosing to do it here too, only on all pages at once, rather than a single page.

Comment: This is definitely a huge security risk and impossible. What if you visited an arbitrary page, and the page checks your open tabs and essentially knows exactly what you're doing? It could see confidential information from the other tabs, etc....

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow I'm trying to run this from bookmarklet context, not from a web page.  I have to manually run the bookmarklet, meaning that I want it to do whatever it does.  I can already do things from a bookmarklet that I can't from a regular web page, such as open a communications channel with another page to send/receive data from it.

Comment: @Michael Okay, but bookmarklets are not special at all and have no more permissions than any arbitrary script.

Comment: the answer is no, and it's not complicated or negotiable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have done some searching but have found very little documentation on what can be done in a bookmarklet which cannot be done in a normal web page

That is because there is essentially none. For all practical purposes, running a bookmarklet is exactly the same as running script on the page. It is almost precisely equivalent to clicking a link on the page that has `href="javascript:.."`

> although having written some bookmarklets already it seems they have a bit more privileged status than a normal web page (although this seems to vary by browser).

I've have also written and researched a lot about bookmarklets (check my SO history). I have found only 2 significant differences.

1.) You can use `%s` in the bookmark's URL in combination with a bookmark keyword for argument substitution via the URL bar.

2.) There is a weird hack in Chrome (which could easily get closed with some future update) which lets a bookmarklet open a URL in a new tab and then run code in that tab *if and only if* the user does CTRL+click on the bookmarklet. But that still doesn't let you do anything to tabs which are already open.

If you know others, let me know.

The only solution is to create a browser extension. If you can write a bookmarklet, it isn't much more complicated to write a very basic extension.

Answer (score 0):

A bookmarklet is a `javascript` code that is being injected within a webpage;

If multiple tabs are available, the bookmarklet will be injected within the webpage of the current active tab.

The power of a bookmarklet is limitless, but it has effect only on 1 webpage, on the page that has been injected;

What you need here is a `browser extension`.

The extension gives you access to the browsers features;